# Language Detection in Solr

Tags: solr, multilingual, language-detection

I have some documents in different languages and I get Solr detect their languages and index them, so I added following configs to `solrconfig.xml`:

```
 <updateRequestProcessorChain name="langid">
   <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="langid.fl">text,title,subject,description,content</str>
     <str name="langid.langField">language_s</str>
     <str name="langid.overwrite">true</str>
     <str name="langid.map">true</str>
     <str name="langid.map.individual">true</str>

     <str name="langid.fallback">en</str>

   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I'd like to see detected language in a field beside `id`, `content`, `content_type` and `__version__` once I send a general query `*:*` to Solr, . The following is an example of a result I get:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":29,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1533230772660"}},
  "response":{"numFound":18,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"/ifs/language/Gre2",
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "content":[" \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n  Η ελληνική γλώσσα έχει επηρεάσει σημαντικά τις άλλες γλώσσες, τόσο στην πολιτική, όσο και στους επιστημονικούς όρους, στις τέχνες, στη φιλοσοφία, στο θέατρο και γενικά σε τομείς στους οποίους είχε προηγηθεί κοινωνικά και, κατά συνέπεια, γλωσσολογικά. Υπήρξε για μεγάλο διάστημα η lingua franca της ανατολικής και δυτικής Μεσογείου και τα πρώτα χριστιανικά κείμενα γράφτηκαν σε αυτήν. Οι Λατίνοι επηρεάστηκαν βαθύτατα από τα ελληνικά που ήταν πλουσιότερη γλώσσα τότε και έτσι πολλά ελληνικά στοιχεία εντάχθηκαν σχεδόν αυτούσια στα λατινικά, από τα οποία εν συνεχεία εντάχθηκαν και σε άλλες συγγενείς προς τα λατινικά γλώσσες. Με την σειρά τους τα ελληνικά επηρεάστηκαν κι αυτά από την γλώσσα λαών που κατέκτησαν την χώρα είτε με πολέμους είτε οικονομικά, με αποτέλεσμα στην διάρκεια των αιώνων να μπουν στο ελληνικό λεξιλόγιο λατινικές λέξεις, ενετικές και τουρκικές.\n \n  "],
        "_version_":1607701684376567808},
      {
        "id":"/ifs/language/Ger1",
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "content":[" \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n  Eine parallele Bildung ist schon im gotischen Adverb þiudiskō belegt, mit dem der griechische Ausdruck ethnikṓs, heidnisch‘ übersetzt wurde. Später wurde auch das altenglische þēodisc in gleicher Weise für lat. gentīlis ,heidnisch‘ verwendet. In seiner lateinischen Form „theodisce“ findet man das Wort erstmals in einem Synodenbericht des päpstlichen Nuntius Gregor von Ostia aus dem Jahre 786. Dieser Bericht über zwei Synoden, die in England stattfanden, wurde sowohl auf Lateinisch als auch in der Sprache des Volkes verlesen. Aus dem Kontext geht hervor, dass hier die altenglische Sprache im Gegensatz zu dem vom Klerus verwendeten Latein gemeint war. Nur zwei Jahre jünger ist der erste Beleg aus dem kontinental-germanischen Sprachgebiet, als in einer Anklage gegen den baierischen Herzog Tassilo auf dem Reichstag zu Ingelheim eine germanische Übersetzung für dessen „Fahnenflucht“ genannt wurde: „quod theodisca lingua harisliz dicitur“.\n \n  "],
        "_version_":1607701684751958016},
```

Am I missing something that I can't see `language_s` field in the shown fields?

Comment: How are you indexing your content? Have you configured the langid update processor to run when you're sending new content to Solr? Do you have a `language_s` field (or `*_s` dynamic field) defined? Update processors run when you're sending new content to Solr, not when you're querying.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the idea!
1. I simply use `curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true' -F "myfile=@example/exampledocs/solr-word.pdf"` to index a document, so how can I add lingid update processor configuration here?
2. What is the type of `language_s ` if I wanna add it as a field to the schema?

Comment: `*_s` is a dynamic string field by default. You request a specific chain by giving `update.chain=<name of chain>` as an argument in the URL, so `update.chain=langid&literal.id=...` should work in this case.

Comment: Progress! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I work in a structure which doesn't give me much of freedom to upload a config file, so is there any way to make changes in `updateRequestProcessorChain` with a `http` request, or something?
( I know how to add a `updateProcessor` with a `json` overlay, but I'm not sure how to do for a `updateRequestProcessorChain`)